# If we aren't obligated in 613, why ask for reward for 613?

Tags: mitzvah

This is based on some preconceived notions I have so if my premises are wrong, please let me know.

I am not bound to all 613 mitzvot. I get this from [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/541686/jewish/How-Many-of-the-Torahs-Commandments-Still-Apply.htm), and through a look at the Rambam's [list](http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm). Some simply don't and can't apply to me -- and this includes negatives (a woman shouldn't wear men's clothing) and positives (that a Kohein should put on the proper garments for the service).

I know that (from reading related questions) there is some reward for fulfilling mitzvot I am not obligated in, though less than for someone who is obligated in them, but as far as I understand, I do not get a reward for mitzvot that I can't fulfill (unless one counts "learning about them" as equivalent), or even ones that don't apply to me that I DO fulfill (if I wear the priestly garments and perform the service, I can't imagine that I get any reward for kiyum hamitzvah - in fact, I would assume that it would be problematic).

Why then do I ask that my performance of certain mitzvot should be considered as if I fulfilled all 613? I say things like

> כְּאִלּוּ קִיַּמְתִּיהָ בְּכָל פְּרָטֶיהָ וְדִקְדּוּקֶיהָ וְכַוָּנותֶיהָ וְתַרְיַ"ג מִצְות הַתְּלוּיִם בָּהּ.

The Artscroll translation is May it be your will that (insert commandment here) be as worthy "as if I had fulfilled it in all its details, implications and intentions as well as the six hundred and thirteen commandments that are dependent on it."

Why do I want to be considered as if I had fulfilled 613 mitzvot when some of them are not meant for me and, were I to fulfill them, I would not receive any reward (and it might even be a bad thing)?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify when you are saying this formulation, but if you are saying it when performing the *mitzvah* of *tzitzit* and the *mitzvah* of *tefillin* we can perhaps explain it in a different sense. Both *tzitzit* and *tefillin* are associated with all the *mitzvot*:

**Menachot 43b**

> תניא אידך וראיתם אותו וזכרתם את כל מצות ה' שקולה מצוה זו כנגד כל המצות כולן ותניא אידך וראיתם אותו וזכרתם ועשיתם ראיה מביאה לידי זכירה זכירה מביאה לידי עשיה
>
> And another [Baraitha] taught: ‘That ye may
>   look upon it and remember all the commandments of the Lord’: this precept is equal to all the precepts together. And another [Baraitha] taught: ‘That ye may look upon it and remember... and do them’: looking [upon it] leads to remembering [the commandments], and remembering leads to doing them.
>
> (Soncino translation)

**Midrash Seichel Tov Shemot 13:16**

> גדולה היא יציאת מצרים שצריכה אות וטוטפות להזכירה כנגד כל המצות

Thus, when performing these *mitzvot* it makes sense to mention 613 *mitzvot* because all 613 *mitzvot* are connected to the current *mitzvah*. Even if you personally cannot fulfill a particular *mitzvah*, every *mitzvah* is still associated with *tzitzit* and *tefillin*.