# 613 Mitzvos depend on another?

Tags: mitzvah, tefilin, prayer-book, tzitzis, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I've noticed the following phrase in a couple places in the *siddur*:

> שֶׁתְּ֒הֵא חֲשׁוּבָה מִצְוַת _ לְפָנֶֽיךָ
> כְּאִלּוּ קִיַּמְתִּֽיהָ בְּכָל פְּרָטֶֽיהָ וְדִקְדּוּקֶֽיהָ וְכַוָּנוֹתֶֽיהָ
> **וְתַרְיַ"ג מִצְווֹת הַתְּ֒לוּיוֹת בָּהּ**
>
> to consider [my fulfillment of] the mitzvah of _ before You as though I had fulfilled it in every detail, accurately and with full intent, and the 613 commandments that depend on it. Amein, Selah.

Once before putting on [*tzitzis*](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Tzitzit.2), and once before putting on [*tefillin*](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Tefillin). This year I took note that it also appears before taking the four species.

I'm specifically intrigued by the phrase "613 *mitzvos* which are dependant upon it". **What does this phrase mean?** I know that *tzitzis* are considered equivalent to all the 613 *mitzvos* ([Nedarim 25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.25a.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)), so perhaps this is a reference to that, but where do *tefillin* and the four species (which don't have this status) fit in?<sup>1</sup>

**Does this phrase appear elsewhere in the liturgy which I am missing?**

Edit: Not in standard *siddurim*, I did find that the **Chida** [composed a prayer](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=169536&pagenum=13) before performing *pidyon haben* in which he writes the same formula.

Edit2: In my *Machzor* for Sukkos, in the *Ushpizin* section, I found this formula with regards to the *mitzvah* of Sukkah.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that Sefaria siddur's commentary (I think the Metsudah siddur by Rabbi Avrohom Davis) on the prayer before *tzitzis* makes the same connection I suggested. However, they don't comment on *tefillin*. Perhaps this comment was taken from the [**Pele Yoetz**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14116&st=&pgnum=98), who writes similarly.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78441/how-are-all-613-mitzvot-dependent-on-one-mitzvah

Comment: Partial duplicate? @rosends

Comment: It's interesting that אתרוג has a gematria of 610. If you add the other three species, you get 613.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108695/if-we-arent-obligated-in-613-why-ask-for-reward-for-613